# How do I force a file action in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, syntax, error-handling

I'm working on a project where I need to convert a few thousand documents from HTML to Word. I'm working with this function:

```
function saveas-document ($docs) {         
        $opendoc = $word.documents.open($docs);    
        $savepath = $docs -replace [regex]::escape($htmPath),"$docpath"
        $opendoc.saveas([ref]"$savepath", [ref]$saveFormat);         
        $opendoc.close();
}
```

Recently, while testing, my job stalled because one of the documents is locked by "another user". I get a dialog box asking me if I want a read ony copy, if I want to edit and merge changes later, or wait for notification that the document is available again. Also, in either case where I choose to open the file, that seems to override my `$word.Visible-$False` parameter.

I've been unsuccessful in identifying this "another user" that's locked my document. All the documents are on a local, non-shared drive, so I'm not sure what's got them locked. Based on where the files live, I'm confident that nothing needs to be edited, and I could just force the file open, then `Save As...`

Can I use `-force` as a parameter in this function? Where is the best place to place that parameter?

EDIT: Per JPBlanc below, I tried stopping Word and got three errors per record.

```
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass] doesn't contain a method named 'quit'.
At C:\users\x46332\desktop\sad003.ps1:69 char:18
+     $opendoc.quit <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (quit:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Exception calling "SaveAs" with "16" argument(s): "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be
 used."
At C:\users\x46332\desktop\sad003.ps1:73 char:20
+     $opendoc.saveas <<<< ([ref]"$savepath", [ref]$saveFormat);
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Exception calling "Close" with "3" argument(s): "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be u
sed."
At C:\users\x46332\desktop\sad003.ps1:74 char:19
+     $opendoc.close <<<< ();
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding the readonly variant to the method, it is the second variant, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb216319(v=office.12).aspx.

ie:

```
$opendoc = $word.documents.open($docs,$false,$true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I just think tha your are the "another user", this just because $opendoc.close(); is not enough to free the access to the file.

Can you try to add :

```
# Stop Winword Process
$opendoc.quit()
$rc = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($opendoc)
```

Assuming you are opening your word document with :

```
$opendoc = new-object -com "word.application"
```

Comment: Crap. OK. I'll keep digging. Thanks anyway.